# Delete records without refreshing PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql, mysqli

i'm tyring to delete some records from my database but without going to the delete.php file or refreshing the page.

i tried this code:

lieferant.php

```
   <td> <?php echo    $row['lieferantID']; ?>  </td>

   <td> <?php echo    $row['lieferantname']; ?>  </td>

   <td> <?php echo    $row['kontakt']; ?>  </td>

   <td> <?php echo    $row['mail']; ?>  </td>

<td>  <button type="button" id="<?php echo $row['lieferantID']; ?>" class="delete-btn">Delete</button></td>


<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(function() {

            $(".delete-btn").click(function() {
                var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
                var info = {"lieferantID": del_id};
                if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "delete.php", //URL to the delete php script
                        data : info,
                        success : function() {
                        }
                    });
                    $(this).parents(".record").animate("fast").animate({
                        opacity : "hide"
                    }, "slow");
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
 </script>
```

delete.php

```
$lieferantID=$_POST['lieferantID'];
$delete=mysqli_query($connection,"DELETE FROM 'lieferant' WHERE lieferantID='$lieferantID'");
$result = mysqli_query($delete) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Unfortunetely it doesn't work.  When i put the ID of the row manuelly in the query it will be deleted without going to the delete.php, but still i have to refresh the page to see that the record is gone, so my question is:

1.how can i pass the 'lieferantID' (the ID of the row) to my delete.php, so that it works automatically
2.how can the page "refresh" itself?

thanks for any help :)

Comment: `var del_id = $(this).attr("lieferantID");` Does your button actually have an attribute called `lieferantID`?

Comment: Hi this `$(this).attr("lieferantID")` should be `$(this).attr("id")` . Also add this `type="button"` to your button

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: Typo: `'lieferantID' + del_id;` should be `'lieferantID=' + del_id;` or better maintain it as an object not a string

Comment: @Swati I changed everything what y'all said but it still don't work :/

Comment: are you seeing any error inside browser console ?

Answer (score 1):

you should change

```js
var del_id = $(this).attr("lieferantID");
```

to

```
var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
```

since you use `id` in `button` element.

and try this

```
 var info = {lieferantID: del_id};
```

instead of

```
var info = 'lieferantID' + del_id;
```

for the refresh part you can use this

```
setInterval('location.reload()', 1000);
```

inside `success`
so the final code look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(function() {

            $(".delete-btn").click(function() {
                var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
                var info = {lieferantID: del_id};
                if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "delete.php", //URL to the delete php script
                        data : info,
                        success : function() {
                            setInterval('location.reload()', 1000);
                        }
                    });
                    $(this).parents(".record").animate("fast").animate({
                        opacity : "hide"
                    }, "slow");
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
 </script>
```

or you can hide that row after success response without refreshing the page.

Comment: it's not working either :(

Answer (score 0):

You're sending wrong thing to post request. Use this

```
var info = {"lieferantID": del_id};
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "delete.php",
        data : info,
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function() {
            setInterval('location.reload()', 1000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work :|

Comment: could you try again ?

Comment: i did it now but it still doesn't work..